# Regular Expression for Value not greater than 6 with 1 decimal digit?

Tags: regex

Values accepted:

```
6.0
5.9
0.0
1.1
6
5
```

not accepted:

```
6.01
6.1
5.99
0.00
```

> what i have tried (1 decimal place) don't know how to limit till 6

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$
```

Comment: Use [`^([0-5]\.\d|6\.0)$`](https://regex101.com/r/M5v3D2/2).

Comment: Should add it as an answer...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto: Added with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's not accepting 6 and 5

Comment: @DeepakJain: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/Mygn66/1), it matches `5.0` and `6.0`. Do you mean to say the one fractional digit is optional with all cases?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it should accept the number

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: BTW, what is the regex flavor?

Comment: what do u mean by flavor ?

Comment: Is it JavaScript? XML Schema? C#?

Comment: c# @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, then it is better to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` or use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag when compiling the Regex object. Use `var rx = new Regex(@"^([0-5](?:\.[0-9])?|6(?:\.0)?)$");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^([0-5](?:\.\d)?|6(?:\.0)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5v3D2/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) group:

  - `[0-5](?:\.\d)?` - a digit from `0` to `5` followed with an *optional* sequence of a `.` followed with a single digit
  - `|` - or
  - `6(?:\.0)?` -  `6.0` or `6`
- `)`  - group end
- `$` - end of string

Comment: If your regex engine supports [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), add a `?:` just after the open parenthesis for a performance improvement. That's not significant in this case, but it's a good practice anyway.

Comment: It is good practice, but in this case it is too insignificant to even mention it. The pattern only checks 3 char strings, the overhead is next to none.

Comment: Doesn't really make a huge amount of difference here but just to make anyone else aware as I only recently learnt this myself. [0-9] (or 0-1, 0-2 etc.) is generally better to use than \d, \d also matches other symbols such as some Arabic numerals and most of the time these are not something you are intending to match.

Comment: You learnt the Python 3.x or .NET regex flavor, right? Then here are more things for you to learn: 1) in .NET, you may use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`, and all *capturing* groups become *non-capturing* ones, 2) in .NET and Python 3.x, `\d` and other shorthand classes are Unicode-aware *by default*, in other languages and flavors they are not. However, in .NET, when using `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option (=`re.ASCII`), `\d` will only match ASCII digits (and `\w` will also match only ASCII letters/digits and `_`, as in JavaScript). But is a comment a good place to re-write a regex cheatsheet?

Comment: MySQL/POSIX/XSD Schema regex flavors do not support non-capturing groups. Well, XSD Schema does not support `^` and `$` since all XSD patterns are anchored by default.